# PASS and RECIEVE data in Redirect - React Hooks

Tags: reactjs

After searching on Google! I didn't find any solution, please Help!

I have component with PreSignup Form that collect EMAIL and PASSWORD like code bellow.

What I want is to pass the email and password to the FullSignup From in another component with redirect

Scenario :

1. Fill email and password fields
2. click btn Save => then redirect to /fullsignup component
3. In Fullsignup, How can i get the email and password value from PreSignup component?

```
// presignup.js
const PreSignup = props => {

const [infos, setInfos] = useState({
    email : '',
    password : '',
    isFilled : false
})
...
const handleChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const name = event.target.name;
    const values = event.target.value;
    setInfos({...infos, [name] : values})
}
const saveAndNext = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const presave = {
        email : infos.email,
        password : infos.password
    }
    setInfos({isFilled : true})
}
const {isFilled} = infos
if (isFilled) {
    return (
        <Redirect to={{
            pathname :'/fill/3/profile/',
            state : {infos || // anything you suggest}
            }}/>
    )
}
...

// fullsignup.js
const FullSignup = () => {
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    email : // this is fill from Presignup
    password : // this is fill from Presignup
  name : ''
// ...others 
})
// here i can use email and password without demanding new email and password!
//example
console.log(values.email, values.password) // return the values filled in Presignup component
return (
...
)
}
```

Comment: Are you using Context or Redux for state management?  This is a  situation where your app is getting quite complex and you may need to revisit your state management.

Comment: No I dont use - Is useContext can fix it? I hadn't use Context or Redux before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see from your code, you have already done with navigating to fullsignup page with user informations. There is only thing you need to do to get these datas from fullsignup page. When you need these data, you can get them by `props.location.state.infos`

Comment: Thanks  @Murat Celik ! it works I need to add spread for infos before `isFilled : true` in saveAndNext like this : `setInfos({...infos, isFilled : true})`